# Min/Max on x-axis not honored in Highstocks version of xrange chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to enforce x-axis to set min and max values, but it does not seem to take effect in Highstock version. It appears to take the min and max values from series values instead.  Please advise.

Highcharts verion (works fine)
https://jsfiddle.net/bcs47nkg/

Highstocks version (not working)
http://jsfiddle.net/2pq0z1ht/

```
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'xrange',
        },

        xAxis: {
            min: Date.UTC(2014, 1, 20),
            max: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 20),
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                gapSize: 2
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            y: 0,
            partialFill: 0.25
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
            y: 1
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
            y: 2
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
            y: 1
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
            y: 2
        }],
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable `ordinal` option and also set `min` and `max` for `xAxis` in a navigator:

```
    xAxis: {
        ordinal: false,
        max: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 20),
        min: Date.UTC(2014, 1, 20)
    },

    navigator: {
        xAxis: {
            min: Date.UTC(2014, 1, 20),
            max: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 20)
        }
    },
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3xesdLbp/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.xAxis.min

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: This is it. This is exactly what I was asking. Thank you Sir!